# How to convert a dependency graph to series-parallel representation?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, partial-order

I'm given a finite partial order, in the form of a dependency graph between items, and I'd like to have it in series-parallel form ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series-parallel_partial_order)).

So formally, given a finite partial order $\le$ on a set $V$, I'd like to construct it using only the following rules:

- For every item $P$ in $V$, we have the partial order on $\{P\}$.
- *Series.* If we have orders $X$ and $Y$, then we also have $X;Y$, which adds both orders such that additionally for any $x,y \in X,Y$ we have $x \le y$.
- *Parallel.* If we have orders $X$ and $Y$, then we also have $X + Y$, which adds both orders such that any $x,y \in X,Y$ are incomparable ($x \not\le y \land y \not\le x$).

**What kind of algorithm could I use to construct this SP-form?**

(I'm aware that the graph is required to be "N-free" for an SP-form to exist.)

For a larger graph which is regularly updated, it would be helpful if the algorithm were incremental, but I have no idea whether that would be possible.

*Examples.*  Writing $P$ for the partial order on the single-element set $\{P\}$, a linear order would look like $A;B;C;...$ (all in sequence).  The "unorder", where different items are incomparable, would look like $A+B+C+...$ (all in parallel).  A binary tree could look like $A;((B;(C+D))+(E;(F+G)))$.

*Background.*  In a task list or issue tracking application which allows you to specify dependencies between tasks or issues, it seems helpful to present them in a series-parallel form, instead of the usual flat list which at most is topologically sorted.

Comment: Is it the same problem as discussed here https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a6a7/15c793c76229f4f47e4a915846ca0a5302cb.pdf ?